# Data is not populated when website add in Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics

Here I am trying to add this website "http://www.ngi.ae/" in Google Analytics. For this first I created account and added this website then when I click on audience all figures are displayed as 0. What should I do?

Check this image 2 where audience is 0.

[image: image1]

Note: This is not my website/blog. This is another public website like every normal company website have. So I want to fetch data from public websites.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics wont collect data from a website unless you add the tracking code for the GA property that you created. Simply creating an account and property in GA for a site will not automatically have it collect data on that site. If you do have the website owner's permission to track the site, then tracking data will not be retroactive to adding the tracking code snippet, it will only track data going forward from the time it is installed.